# Link na barra de StatusBar Delphi 10

Tags: delphi

Preciso colocar um link na barra de status do sistema, clicando nela vai abrir uma outra função que já esta pronta, a `StatusBar` possui 3 *panels* e somente a 3 deve abrir quando clicar. Estou usando o evento `OnDrawPanel` para tentar formatar o texto em formato de link.

Segue o código:

```
procedure TfAAA001.StatusBar1DrawPanel(StatusBar: TStatusBar; Panel: TStatusPanel; const Rect: TRect);
begin
  if Panel.Index = 2 then
  begin
    StatusBar1.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlue;
    StatusBar1.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
    StatusBar1.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Right, Rect.Top + 1, Panel.Text);
  end;
end;
```

Assim a `StatusBar` não esta iniciando, alguém sabe como resolver.

Comment: Conseguiu realizar os testes com a resposta que propus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O código está correto, porém para disparar o evento `OnDrawPanel` precisa setar a propriedade style do *panel* como `psOwnerDraw`.

Isto pode ser feito tanto em design ou via código.

Penso em algo no Create do form, algo como:

```
StatusBar1.Panels.Items[2].Style := psOwnerDraw;
```

Agora para o click:

```
var
  vPosicao: Tpoint;
begin
  vPosicao := ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos);

  if vPosicao.x <= StatusBar1.Panels[0].Width then
    ShowMessage('Clicou no Primeiro')
  else if vPosicao.x <= (StatusBar1.Panels[0].Width + StatusBar1.Panels[1].Width) then
    ShowMessage('Clicou no Segundo')
  else
    ShowMessage('Clicou no Terceiro');
end;
```

Comment: resolvi de uma forma diferente mas foi com este conceito, usei 3 eventos, ondraw, onclick e onmousemouve

ondraw usei um codigo para formatar o statusbar specifico como um link, deixando azul, e sublinhado.

usando uma função parecida com esta sua eu recebia a posição no omousemove, que quando era a que eu queria trocava o cursor para um tipo de link.

e na onclick era a função para abrir realmente o link.